# IMG does not shows in visual studio 2019

Tags: html, visual-studio-2019

I have an issue with visual studio web site as it doesnt load images. I have tried multiple solution yet no results. Simple code:

```
<img src="Bin/Piotr.png" alt="Piotr" width="25" height="25" />
```

Does not display image.
I have checked:

- if path is correct, it is.
- If file is not corrupted, it is not
- if filepath in dev tools is correct, it is

[Image Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPrqs.png)

however I cant see "bin" folder in source (which is leading to conclusion that i did something wrong and Bin is private or blocked)

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9Ekx.png)

EDIT:
I have noticed that folder, where image is, is not on the file source list:
[Solution Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wB84.png)

There is a missing folder BIN, therefore question is how can I add this folder?

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension called path in vscode install it and also check your data if exists inside the bin folder then try this /src/bin

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have tried to locate this extension but all i have found is File Path On Footer, anyway... I have tried to move image to same directory, yet no joy. I have a feeling that i did something trivial that stopping code :/. Just need to find it :)